# How can I disable an array of days in 'date-picker' when install "element-ui": "^2.3.7"?

Tags: datepicker, vuejs2, element-ui

I installed  "element-ui": "^2.3.7" and I use it in my Vue component :

```
<el-date-picker
          v-model="valueDateTimeOrder"
          type="daterange"
          align="right"
          unlink-panels
          range-separator="To"
          start-placeholder="Start date"
          end-placeholder="End date"
          :picker-options = "pickerOptions">
        </el-date-picker>
```

in data:

```
 pickerOptions: {
      disabledDate(time) {
        return time.getTime() > Date.now();
      },
    }
```

It's works perfect. But when I want to disable all in an array, I don't know how to do it. Because the array only exist after get api. But data is done after all this component, it cannot wait call the range. Help me to set picker-options. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this can help you.

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  var vm = this;
  return {
   disabledDates: [],
   pickerOptions1: {
    disabledDate(time) {
     time = moment(time).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     return vm.disabledDates.indexOf(time)>-1;
    }
   },
   value1: '',
   val: ''
  };
 },
 methods: {
  appendDate () {
   this.disabledDates.push(this.val);
        this.$refs.picker.unmountPicker();
        this.$refs.picker.mountPicker();
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app" style="height:500px;">
  <div class="block">
    <el-date-picker
      ref="picker"
      v-model="value1"
      type="date"
      :picker-options="pickerOptions1"
      placeholder="select date">
    </el-date-picker>
    <div>
     disabledDates:{{disabledDates}}<br>
     <input type="text" v-model="val"><button @click="appendDate">append date into disabled date array(format:YYYY-MM-DD)</button>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll use your idea to update my code. Thanks :))

Comment: It seemed that you've forgot to accept and vote my answer :-)

Comment: Eres un admin !!